# Apache HTML writing on Raspbian

Tags: php, apache, raspbian

I currently have a PI3 on my home network.
With my LAMP apache, I keep the www folder on the USB drive -  let's call it `/media/USB32/www`.
Oh- the USB partition is formatted as FAT32.

Assume my `user id` is `Tony`. I have added this `user-id` to group `www-data`.

I can access the `www` folder for editing from a Windows PC, and I can read and write on it using `puTTY`.

Apache can show a webpage on it, but **Apache cannot write or update a file** on it via a HTML Form  using Fopen or Fwrite.

I'm pretty sure my PHP below is correct.-

```js
function customError($errno, $errstr) {
  echo "<br/><b>Error!:</b> [$errno] $errstr";
  }  
set_error_handler("customError");       //set error handler

echo "HERE GOES OPEN, WRITE and CLOSE";
$fp = fopen('dddata.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, 'Our WRITE data...');
fwrite($fp, 'Some more crap.....');
fclose($fp);
```

.........

The error given is

> fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Any idea where my error(s) are?

Comment: Your error is that you're passing a boolean to `fwrite()` when you should be passing a resource. I'd suggest checking the result of your `fopen()` call before trying to use it. Also you may want to look at `file_put_contents()` which is much easier to use for most cases. And don't let your web server write to the same folder it serves from. Use a temp directory.

Comment: Sorry- I should have concentrated on the fopen,  not the fwrite.  The error given by FOPEN is  [2] fopen(dddata.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied    Seems to be a permission problem. (obviously)

Comment: Don't worry- Once this is (if ever) operational, the user will be writing to a completely different remote folder.

Comment: You might want to change that schedule, as permissions are probably your problem and I'd guess you're not going to get it working without moving that file somewhere else.

Comment: Brief addendum (mostly for myself) - exhausted all file permissions; I suspect it may be something in the Apache conf file(s)

Comment: The Apache config has nothing to do with whether you can write files. Have you tried writing to a different folder as I suggested? I’d try `/tmp` to start with. And have you verified what `fopen()` is returning? Manual says “If the fooen fails an error of level E_WARNING is generated.”

Comment: I just discovered that the owner and group that the www belongs to is "tony" i.e. the user.  Shouldn't this belong to Apache? Or root?  I tried a sudo chown to change the ownership of the www (on a FAT32 USB) to root but got an "operation not permiited" Even when using root. This likely due to the FAT32. I'll shut down Apache, and then remove the fstab entry for it. If this does not work, perhaps I can backup the whole USB partition, and reformat it as EXT4. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181700/discussion-between-aqk-and-miken32).